# How could Bumblebee have worked with Hot Rod?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-the-last-knight

In *The Last Knight*, it's revealed that Bumblebee fought alongside Hot Rod (or a Hot Rod looking fella) in an earlier World War (as in Earth).

Have any interviews, promotional materials, or other works hinted at how this was possible?

How long has Bumblebee been on Earth and why didn't he [arrive with the "initial" Autobot group](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTcHRK2hfIQ)?

Comment: Maybe he was chasing Megatron. Or possibly just ended up on Earth when all the autobots scattered when their planet was destroyed and didn't realise the others were alive until later.