# How did Bumblebee come from space if he was already on Earth during WWII?

Tags: transformers, transformers-2007, transformers-live-action-series

How did Bumblebee fall from space to Sam Witwicky if in the latest movie Bumblebee was on earth in World War 2 and fighting. Did he go back into space or what? As I heard, the new Bumblebee movie is going to be a prequel and he is going to be a VW Bug. Are we supposed to just forget this or was there an explaination that I missed?

Comment: We never see him fall from space in the first movie. He and the Decepticons are already on Earth at the start of the movie. It's unclear from that movie just how long they've been here.

Comment: @phantom42 is right. But also, don't think too hard about the logic of the Transformers, it'll make your head hurt.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I seem to recall something in the first movie about Bumblebee being an advance scout.  I think it was implied that he was here even before the other Autobots arrived.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162180/how-could-bumblebee-have-worked-with-hot-rod

Comment: Trust me on this one: Forget everything and pretend the Bumblebee Movie is just a standalone film.

Comment: Ask Gloria Gaynor.

Comment: I think you’re supposed to forget each Transformers movie as soon as you’ve seen it. Except for [the best one](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_1AWgJ5e-vYPcXdqsA7Up4_MTCSWrAAv).

Answer (score 2):

> Are we supposed to just forget this or was there an explanation that I missed?

While this sounds a little facetious, I think that you *are* supposed to forget. Continuity in the Transformers Movie franchise has not been one of its strong points.

In any long running series, you are going to struggle with continuity. Even in cases where an author has sole control, things will be missed and sometimes events will not quite add up. (A lot of the questions on this site are due to this)

However this gets even more difficult when there are no long-term plans, and numerous different creative people are involved. Star wars and Marvel (movies) try to have some mechanisms to resolve this (see [Lucasfilm Story Group](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lucasfilm_Story_Group) for an example). However, the Transformers franchise does not seem to have the same guidance.

So as a suggestion, if you see the movie, perhaps consider it a stand-alone work which may enhance your enjoyment of it. While there may be bits that tie into other works, there may also be parts that make no sense. If you try to think too hard about it it may stop you from enjoying the Movie.

Comment: Is continuity even *a* point?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of fan theories shared online that this film may serve to reboot the Transformers franchise.

[Screen Rant - How Bumblebee Could Accidentally Soft Reboot Transformers](https://screenrant.com/bumblebee-movie-transformers-reboot/)

There's a feeling that since this film is a prequel, it could rewrite the history for the series. Section 7 is there, in the person of John Cena, but this far earlier story might serve as a starting point for a new series of films, perhaps with a lighter tone.

Optimus Prime is to appear, and there's a hope that his design may be closer to the G1 look, as Bumblebee's is.